# !TouchPlatform.isTouch остается false и из-за этого анимация проигрывается не полностью

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

При прыжке `!TouchPlatform.isTouch` на некоторое время остается как false, из-за чего `isJump` меняется сразу на false и анимация начала прыжка проигрывается не полностью.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!isJump && !TouchPlatform.isTouch)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("isFall");
    }
    isJump = isJump && !TouchPlatform.isTouch;

    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) && TouchPlatform.isTouch)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        animator.SetTrigger("StartJump");
        isJump = true;
    }
}
```

Вот еще код для проверки положения объекта на платформе

```
public class TouchPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isTouch;

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
        {
            isTouch = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
        {
            isTouch = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Если заменить вот эту строчку `isJump = isJump && !TouchPlatform.isTouch;` на вот эту `isJump = isJump && rb.velocity.y > 0` то все работает как надо, но мне интересно почему все-таки в изначальном варианте объект как будто находится на земле, хотя клавиша для прыжка уже нажата и в меню unity переменная `isTouch` стоит как false во время прыжка. При дебаггинге все работает как надо.